# Properties set vs. set construct in Vala

Tags: vala

```
public int val { get; set construct; }
public int val { get; set; }
```

Both can be 'publicly' read, 'publicly' written, and written in constructor... Are the two equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has something to do with GObject style construction.

The parameter is installed using the [G_PARAM_CONSTRUCT](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-GParamSpec.html#G-PARAM-CONSTRUCT:CAPS) ParamFlag when `construct` is specified.

I haven't looked deeper into properties yet, but as I understand it so far it means that the property is set early in the construction process when this flag is set.

There is also a G_PARAM_CONSTRUCT_ONLY flag that allows the property to be set **only** at construction time. I don't know if Vala has support for this though.

It's mentioned in the [Object Construction topic](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/howto-gobject-construction.html) of the GObject manual.

Comment: The Object Construction page appears to be for C rather than Vala. How does this relate to Vala code? (e.g. if you're using VAPI generated interfaces to C classes, which have a CONSTRUCT_ONLY parameter)